# How to iterate over a list in search of the longest series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

If I have a list of numbers $1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0$ that I want to iterate over to find the longest series of numbers (i.e., $1, 1, 1$)how can I show this function in a formal notation?

$R$ is the list.

I've attempted something similar to how the source code works but I keep getting stuck on how to count each element.

[image]

Comment: That sounds like something that is about 20 times easier to explain in English prose than to try to shoehorn it into symbolic notation and then burden the reader with unpacking your meaning afterwards.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - I know right, but I still need to show it in some sort of formal / set theory mess

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the longest series of $1$'s among zeros, it can be expressed like
$$
\max_{1\le i\le j\le n} \left[(j-i+1)\cdot\prod_{k=i}^{j}R_k\right]
$$
where $n$ is the number of elements in $R$.

EDIT. Just for *fun* to get rid of $\max$ (this is bad on so many levels..., notice the exponents $n^2$). Do not use!
$$
\left\lfloor\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}(j-i+1)^{n^2}\prod_{k=i}^{j}R_k\right)^{1/n^2}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: You've lost me with the n^2 bit, how does this find the longest number of elements in the list?

Comment: @Crizly  Informally, because if you have some numbers, say $3,2,1,0,3$ and you want to find the max, you can take a large power, say $20$ and compute $\lfloor(3^{20}+2^{20}+1^{20}+0^{20}+3^{20})^{1/20}\rfloor$ because the power is so high that the max element "wins" againts the others and then when you take the $20$-th root and the floor you still get the max ($3$). Clearly the exponent has to be large enough that if you have many values=max like $3,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3$, the number of values in the sum does not make the result bigger than max. Here $n^2$ is a large enough exponent.

Comment: Seems very hacky

Comment: @Crizly  It is. Indeed I wrote "Do not use!".